# Laravel route thinks function is something else

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

What I have is a website where you sign up and it sends a link with a token to your email address to choose a password; when you go to the link given which would like something like this;

`branch/pass/token_here`

So this is the route I have which helps this;

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('pass/{token}', 'PassController@getToken');
```

and I have this in;

**PassController.php** in the getToken function

```
public function getToken($token) {
    //I do stuff with the token here
}
```

I also have this function in the **PassController.php** file

```
public function getPassword() {
    //When a user enters the password in the box provided it should come to this function and do stuff
}
```

But when I navigate to

`branch/pass/password`

It sees the word 'password' as the token itself, is there anyway to get around this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a page that calls `getPassword()` you need to add a new route for it:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('pass/password', 'PassController@getPassword');
Route::get('pass/{token}', 'PassController@getToken');
```

And you call it via url `branch/pass/password`.

However, I would recommend you to keep those two routes not sharing the `pass` segment, just for the sake of not confusing whether it's a request to do stuff with the token, or to do with the password. For example:

```
Route::get('password', 'PassController@getPassword');
Route::get('token/{token}', 'PassController@getToken');
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I have included this as you suggested but now I get this error `405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: I suppose you get to the password route via a form right? Try Route::post('password' ...